# Como criar um app em Phonegap usando uma página online?

Tags: apache-cordova, mobile, phonegap-buillder

Gostaria de criar um aplicativo que necessite de atualização de dados constante, manutenção rápida e desenvolvimento em um prazo muito curto, o aplicativo não tem exigências alem de exibir informações para o usuário.

Acredito que a melhor solução seria um app que "navegasse" em uma página web, cujo vai assumir o papel do aplicativo exibindo as informações, como a maioria dos aplicativos do FirefoxOS faz, entretanto não achei nenhum tutorial especifico, só achei para rodar a aplicação local (no celular) e requisitar dados do servidor.

Como posso desenvolver? é permitido em todas as versões do Android um IFRAME por exemplo?

*obs: o aplicativo será apenas para Android*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se o aplicativo sera apenas para Android, não tem porque você utilizar o Phonegap, pois uma das premissas dele é que, com o mesmo código você possa criar app para diversas plataformas.

Você pode fazer em Java Puro, sera simples a manutenção, se você ja tiver o site hospedado em algum servidor.

Você usara o componente WebView.

Crie um projeto android normalmente e no arquivo

> MainActivity.java

Coloque este código abaixo:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private Button button;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final Context context = this;

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonUrl);

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(context, WebViewActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }

        });

    }

}
```

No arquivo

> WebViewActivity.java

Coloque este código:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class WebViewActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView webView;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.webview);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        //webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");

        String customHtml = "<html><body><h1>Hello, WebView</h1></body></html>";
        webView.loadData(customHtml, "text/html", "UTF-8");

    }

}
```

Neste site [Android WebView example](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-webview-example/) você encontrara exemplos mais completos e complexos e poderá melhorar sua aplicação.

Answer (score 2):

O que você pode fazer (e eu já fiz) é criar um app que 'chame' o site. O código seria mais ou menos esse:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
      var appd;
      document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
      function onDeviceReady() {
      appd = window.open('http://seusite.com.br', '_blank', 'location=yes');
      }
   </script>

<body>


 <div class="app"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>
```

Isso vai abrir a página que você quer no browser do aparelho.

Espero ter ajudado!